# Elasticsearch return country from query string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type of country in my index that includes a list of country names.   I would like to find any country names that the user might have put into their query.  For example, if the user searches for:

```
car dealerships in japan
```

Then I would like to return the country Japan.  That works for single word countries if I do something like:

```
GET /my_index/country/_search
{
  "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name": {
                  "query": "car dealerships in japan"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

That returns the country Japan, which is what I would like to do.

But if there is more than one word in the country name, I'm not sure how can things up so that it will recognize this.  Otherwise if the query is something like:

```
car dealerships in the united kingdom
```

It will return multiple countries such as United States, United Kingdom, United Arab Emirates... But I would want it only to return united kingdom for this query.

I'm not sure the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying out the synonyms feature of Elasticsearch. As a simple reason for this, consider that your user will not use "united states" all the times, or "united kingdom" all the times in their query. What if the user uses "USA" or "u s a" or "the states" or "england". For these situations you can use this feature.

Here's a starting point:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "u s a,united states,united states of america => usa",
            "g b,gb,great britain,united kingdom, uk, u k => britain,england,scotland,wales",
            "united arab emirates, emirates, arab emirates => emirates"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "country": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And, considering you have these countries in your countries index:

```
{ "index": {}}
{ "name": "japan"}
{ "index": {}}
{ "name": "united kingdom"}
{ "index": {}}
{ "name": "united states"}
{ "index": {}}
{ "name": "united arab emirates"}
```

A search for

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "car dealerships in the uk, japan and emirates"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would give you all three countries:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "country",
        "_id": "CMZe2ygBS4OLL3_lT_B2_Q",
        "_score": 0.03739948,
        "_source": {
           "name": "japan"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "country",
        "_id": "T-e7rg_rTx-3rtTJYxJrBg",
        "_score": 0.03739948,
        "_source": {
           "name": "united arab emirates"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "country",
        "_id": "EqlMu2RiRiSdwyqJa2nyzA",
        "_score": 0.017334092,
        "_source": {
           "name": "united kingdom"
        }
     }
  ]
```

And if you query only one country, only one will be returned:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "car dealerships in the united states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More about this feature [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonym-formats.html).